# What is the lifespan of a Wookie?

Tags: star-wars

I just watched all the Star Wars movies and noticed that in all episodes where Chewbacca appears, he doesn't seems to age at all. It hit me whilst watching "The Force Awakens"

What is the lifespan of a Wookiee?

Or is it a mistake and they forgot to age him?

Comment: Both answers are bogus as they're drawn from the Wookiepedia, and that particular "fact" [is considered "Legend" and not "Canon"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Absolutely_Everything_You_Need_to_Know) if the answerers bothered to read the footnote.  Wookie's lifespan has not been covered in any canon source.

Comment: @JohnnyBones According to the (full Disney Canon) sourcebook "Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know: Journey to Star Wars: The Force Awakens", the lifespan of the average Wookiee is indeed 400 standard years. It seems Wookiepedia draw the information from there, so your argument is irrelevant.

Comment: @PatrickL - Right on the page I linked above: "The book contains the following disclaimer in the back:

In 2014 Lucasfilm reclassified what is considered canon in the Star Wars universe. Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know draws mostly upon information from the Expanded Universe that Lucasfilm now considers to be "Legends"–that is, stories beyond the original six films and the TV shows Star Wars: The Clone Wars and Star Wars Rebels."

Comment: @JohnnyBones So basically you can neither prove nor deny the Canonicity of any information in this book, unless it has been officially revealed or debunked. My answer fits the question, because Canonicity was not mentioned.

Comment: @PatrickL - Well, I believe my last response completely wipes out your edit.  That book is *not* "full Disney Canon".

Comment: @JohnnyBones As I've already written above, there is no need to stay full canon, because the question doesn't mention it. There's no need to argue about that.

Comment: Why is my question being marked down if its getting such response and arguments??!? And why has this question stripped me of my privilege of asking questions?!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in the star wars encyclopedia [wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Wookie) and [this post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/110502) pointing to a (full Disney Canon) sourcebook, the average life expectancy of a Wookiee is about 400 standard years.

Answer (score 4):

According to wookieepedia, Wookies average lifespan is 400 years, but stay rather youthful looking, [http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Wookiee](http://Wookie)

> Wookiees had a long lifespan, appearing not to age over a span of
>   fifty years.